# Grails run app issue ERROR context.ContextLoader

Tags: grails

When I enter run command it throws an error. Here is the output when I run command

```
grails -Dserver.port=8082 run-app
```

output:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java" -Dgrails.home=C:\grails -Dbase.dir=C:\Supreet\Devs@Work\Source\quick-dining "-Dtools.jar=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\lib\tools.jar" -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\grails/conf/groovy-starter.conf -Xmx768M -Xms768M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m -Djline.WindowsTerminal.directConsole=false -javaagent:C:\grails\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars\springloaded-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar -noverify -Dspringloaded=profile=grails -Didea.launcher.port=7537 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.6\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\grails\lib\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy-all\jars\groovy-all-2.3.7.jar;C:\grails\dist\grails-bootstrap-2.4.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.6\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter --main org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner --conf C:\grails/conf/groovy-starter.conf "run-app -plain-output"
|Loading Grails 2.4.4
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
...........
|Compiling 1 source files
.........................
|Running Grails application
Error |
2015-10-07 21:29:27,074 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
Message: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Error |
2015-10-07 21:29:27,176 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
Message: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Did you delete `web-app/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml` ?

Comment: Hi @BurtBeckwith there is no applicationContext.xml  in my  web-app/WEB-INF Folder

Answer (score 1):

If `applicationContext.xml` was deleted, you can restore it pretty easily. Create a new empty app with the same version of Grails and copy the file from there. It's not a file that should be edited, so that should be fine.

Also copy `sitemesh.xml` if it's missing, and the .tld files from `web-app/WEB-INF/tld`.